# java.io.FileNotFoundException:jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final\standlone\temp\temp_folder\xyz.war

Tags: jboss

I deployed the war file in jboss-as-web-7.0.2. `Final\standlone\deployment\xyz.war` file. it deployed successfully. In my war file `WEB-INF\classes\xyz.cer` file is exist. I used the `xyz.cer` file for digital signature. It exist in war file. when i call my webservice it will throw the error `java.io.FileNotFoundException`

**This is the log file:**

```
16:49:58,434 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Administr
ator\Desktop\jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final\standalone\tmp\vfs\temp9f2b48049e74ca68\xxx.war-3c4
430f5fbb60e88\WEB-INF\classes\xyz.cer (The system cannot find the file specif ied)
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, this may mean that you do not have permissions to the file, that the file is currently open in another process which prevents writing to it, or that the file is set to read-only. It is occurred simply due to the lack of proper access permission,